# Xcode error get unable to install errors when I try to launch my app on my phone or my simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm a react native developer and I try to launch the new app on my phone and my simulator.

On my phone, I get this error => Unable to install "MyApp" when I click on details I get this.

```
Details

Unable to install "MyApp"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653179
--
Could not write to the device.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653179
User Info: {
  DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
  MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8000005)";
  "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0  DTDeviceKitBase           0x000000012adfdc8f DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
    1  DTDeviceKitBase           0x000000012ae3c241 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2  DVTFoundation            0x0000000109d8164b DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
    3  DTDeviceKitBase           0x000000012ae3bf82 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1440
    4  IDEiOSSupportCore          0x000000012acaca10 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.292 + 3513
    5  DVTFoundation            0x0000000109eb017e __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6  DVTFoundation            0x0000000109eb1da0 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1191
    7  libdispatch.dylib          0x00007fff204135dd _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8  libdispatch.dylib          0x00007fff204147c7 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9  libdispatch.dylib          0x00007fff2041a5fe _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 606
    10 libdispatch.dylib          0x00007fff2041b0cb _dispatch_lane_invoke + 375
    11 libdispatch.dylib          0x00007fff20424c5d _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 819
    12 libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff205bc499 _pthread_wqthread + 314
    13 libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff205bb467 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--
```

when i try to launch the app on similator i get the same error but its different details =>

```
Please try again later.
invalid symlink at /Users/chocolat/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/82855CE8-7144-4C94-A8E4-70EDE31EAB06/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.W5x1y0/extracted/MyApp.app/assets/App/Assets/Images/test/Lien vers test.png
```

Details simulator errror=>

```
Details

Unable To Install “MyApp”
Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: Please try again later.
Recovery Suggestion: invalid symlink at /Users/chocolat/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/82855CE8-7144-4C94-A8E4-70EDE31EAB06/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.W5x1y0/extracted/MyApp.app/assets/App/Assets/Images/test/Lien vers test.png
--
invalid symlink at /Users/chocolat/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/82855CE8-7144-4C94-A8E4-70EDE31EAB06/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.W5x1y0/extracted/MyApp.app/assets/App/Assets/Images/test/Lien vers test.png
Domain: MIInstallerErrorDomain
Code: 70
User Info: {
  FunctionName = "-[MIFileManager validateSymlinksInURLDoNotEscapeURL:error:]_block_invoke";
  LegacyErrorString = InvalidSymlink;
  SourceFileLine = 1042;
}
--
```

Someone can help me?
Best

System Information

```
macOS Version 11.2.3 (Build 20D91)
Xcode 12.4 (17801) (Build 12D4e)
Timestamp: 2021-04-14T14:26:36+02:00
```

Comment: Any chance you could post more about `Lien vers test.png`? This appears to me to be the issue. Please, if you can, (a) make sure it's in your assets properly, and 9b) post any code trying to use it.

Comment: thanks for response, i already fix the Lien vers test.png inside some weard file but still display the same error when i run app on my simulator

Comment: It still sounds like something related to this asset to me. (1) By saying your issue is "on launch" are you saying it's related to the launch screen?  If so, can you try using a different PNG to see if that's the issue? If not, could you post the code you are using to call up the asset? (2) In case this PNG isn't in your assets, could you verify where it is? Finally (3) Have you tested this on a real device successfully?